# What was the affiliation of the protesters killed in the Gaza protests?

Tags: israel, protests, palestine, gaza

During the recent protests in Gaza, 50 or more protesters were killed by the Israeli military. Israel's official position, as I understand it, is that the majority were members of Hamas or another militant organization. I believe Hamas also claims that most of the people killed were members of Hamas.

This seems possible, but I'm unsure of these statements. Perhaps Israel wants to avoid the appearance of having killed civilians, or perhaps Hamas wants to make their support base seem larger than it is.

What was the affiliation of the protesters killed in the recent Gaza protests? Did most of them belong to Hamas or not? If so, to what extent?

<sub>Note: I'm not asking whether belonging to Hamas is a bad thing, or whether it's justification for shooting someone. I'm only interested in whether most protesters killed were members or not.</sub>

Comment: The cumulative death toll since the protests started stands about [111](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/04/gaza-protest-latest-updates-180406092506561.html). The 55-62 count was for May 14 only.

Comment: Maybe a proper answer needs to include how Hamas membership is determined. Where do you draw the line: Are there card-carrying members of Hamas vs. just supporters vs. like-minded protesters?

Comment: @jeffronicus - That's part of what I'm asking with "to what extent." I don't really want to make a judgment call here on what constitutes Hamas membership, but I am interested to know (if possible) how formal the relationship of those killed with Hamas is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The protests began in late March and
[111](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/04/gaza-protest-latest-updates-180406092506561.html)
Palestinians have been killed by Israeli forces so far. The 50 out
of 62 figure refers to those killed on May 14th.

Tens of thousands have participated on the protests and 5-6000 have
been
injured. [Roughly 60%](https://www.haaretz.com/middle-east-news/palestinians/fifth-week-of-gaza-march-of-return-protests-to-begin-1.6033006)
have been injured by live ammunition from Israeli sniper fire, 15% by
gas inhalation and 25% from other sources. As far as I know, none of
the injured wore any military insignia that would distinguish them
from civilians.

Now to your
question. [Names and photos](https://medium.com/@thepalestineproject/names-and-ages-of-palestinians-killed-by-israeli-troops-in-gaza-29bad3a12db6)
of the killed are available online so identifying them is
trivial. You can easily dig up their Facebook profiles, like the
one for [Ahmed A Aladani](https://www.facebook.com/ahmed.aladini),
apparently killed on May 14th.

Hamas has not clarified which of the killed that came from their
ranks. That is something they otherwise often do when members of their
military wing are killed, by releasing photos of the deceased wearing
their military uniform.

Therefore it is not prudent to take Hamas' figures at face value. It
is in their self-interest to inflate the figures to exaggregate their
involvement in the popular protests. It happens to coincide with
Israel's interest to frame the demonstrations as driven by
Hamas. There is also the question of proportions. If 80% (50/62) of
those who have died came from Hamas, then did 80%, or roughly 2500, of
those injured by sniper fire also come from Hamas? Otherwise why are
Hamas members succumbing to gunshot wounds at a much higher rate than
other Palestinians?

I would say that with the information available currently, there is no
way to answer your question.

Comment: It is dubious that "It is in their self-interest to inflate the figures to exaggregate their involvement in the popular protests." Hamas claims that the protests are driven by the people; it is (at least additionally) in their interest to give a lower number and underplay their role in order to gain international sympathy. Obviously the interview undermined that, and no number was given by their spokesman.

Comment: "Hamas claims that the protests are driven by the people; it is (at least additionally) in their interest to give a lower number and underplay their role in order to gain international sympathy." I doubt that. If someone supports the cause of the Palestinians, s/he will not care much if the killed protesters are from Hamas or not, it is enough that Israel kills people. And if someone supports the Israeli side, s/he will blame Hamas anyway for the killings, be it Hamas members themselves or civilians.

Comment: exaggregate = exaggerate + aggregate? :P

Comment: If this list is to be trusted, among the victims are five 15-year-olds, four 16-year-olds, two 17-year-olds, one 13-year-old, one 14-year-old and one 8-month-old. Were they also supposed to be members of Hamas or another militant organization?

Comment: @EricDuminil (Leaving aside the 8-month old.) Given the horrific state of educational curricula in the [PA](https://www.impact-se.org/reports/palestinian-territories/palestinian-authority/) this is quite plausible.

Comment: @ZevSpitz so... What is your point? It's okay to kill them, just in case? With this logic, you're pretty sure to have the exact same problems and conflict in the next generation. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @EricDuminil Absolutely not. But your question was if children so young could possibly have been members of Hamas or another militant organization; and the answer is, it is quite plausible that these children were engaging in violent behavior towards Israel, and were identified as such.

Answer (score 5):

A senior Hamas Leader, [Salah al-Bardaweel](https://www.cnn.com/2018/05/16/middleeast/hamas-members-gaza-deaths/index.html), claims that of the 62 people killed in the conflict Monday, 50 were members of Hamas. The remaining 12 were non-affiliated.

Comment: Also see https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41260/did-a-hamas-official-claim-that-50-of-62-fatalities-in-gaza-on-14-may-2018-were

Comment: This just repeats the official position of Hamas, which was mentioned in the question.I mentioned a reason to be skeptical of that. Is there any third-party confirmation, etc.?

Comment: Or, at least, is there a reason that any concerns about Hamas wanting to inflate their membership would be incorrect? Or, looking al-Bardaweel's statements, it seems as if he's seeking to defend Hamas from accusations of getting people killed by saying that most of those killed were Hamas's own members.

Comment: Also, note this: "It was unclear if the protesters he was referring to were militants or civilian supporters of the Islamic group, which rules Gaza and opposes Israel's existence." That's part of what I'm asking.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Hmmm. If you're looking for the skeptical approach, skeptics.se might be a better fit for this.

Answer (score -2):

Hamas won the Palestinian legislative elections in 2006, and formed a unity government with Fatah. This unity government was dismissed by the Palestinian Authority's chairman and resulted in a de facto administration of Fatah in the West Bank and Hamas in Gaza. This puts their claim to legitimacy in perspective.

One does not have to belong to a party to signal ones agreement with its legitimacy and it's right to govern. No doubt there are many people in the UK who disagree with the current Conservative government, some more loudly and vociferously than others; but nevertheless, they will agree that they have a legitimate right to govern; no doubt, too, that Israel, given its historical enmity will insist on repeating that Hamas is merely a militant organisation; however, the Palestinian people regard them as their legitimate representative, if not their sole legitimate representative. It's also probably worth noting that in the context of the Palestinian situation, legitimacy is going to contested

I'm not sure then, that the question is well-founded; I mean in the sense of who exactly in the demonstration are members of Hamas; the demonstration was called in large part because of recent US policy moves to bolster Israels claim to Jerusalem and thus the demonstration is essentially an indication of the strength of Palestinian nationalism - and not a party political rally. It does not surprise me that Hamas has released no figures on the party political allegiance of those killed in the recent demonstrations. It seems irrelevant to the cause at hand.

**edit**

There's a report by [Haaretz](https://www.haaretz.com/whdcMobileSite/middle-east-news/palestinians/50-of-dead-in-gaza-protest-were-hamas-activists-says-hamas-official-1.6094899) here reports that a senior Hamas official, Salah Albardaweel said that 'fifty of the 62 killed in Mondays bloody protest were Hamas activists'. This was from a videoed interview that was actually tweeted by the Israeli Defence Force. They also report that Islamic Jihad released a statement that three of those killed belonged to its military wing. They also branded Israels attempt to brand every protestor as a terrorist as 'pathetic'.

A more sceptical view is reported by the [Electronic Intifada](https://electronicintifada.net/blogs/maureen-clare-murphy/50-hamas-members-claim-does-not-justify-gaza-massacre):

> Several of those killed on Monday were buried in Hamas green flag, but not all. Fadi Abu Salmi, a double amputee, was shrouded with the flag of Islamic Jihad. Ahmad al-Adaini was buried in the flag of the leftist Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine.

They add, that this point was also made by the veteran French-Israeli journalist Charles Enderlin:

> "On the Palestinian side, Hamas is presenting itself as victorious, that is to say it had annexed the dead, who most overwhelmingly did not belong to Hamas. Moreover, we did not see many Hamas flags during these demonstrations.

So on the one hand we have Israel attempting to spin legitimate protests as a form of terrorism as they admitted in response to a petition by two Palestinian organisations to a high court:

> Hamas has been leading a new tactic of terrorist activity under the cover of 'national commemoration events' and 'popular protests'.

Given this official view of the Israeli government,  the massacre of protestors and demonstrators on Monday is not surprising. The affiliation of the most of the protestors to Hamas is mostly unsubstantiated and where substantiated showed that the affiliation was more or less negligible and mostly irrelevant. The interview by Albardaweel is admitted by the Electronic Intifada as a major PR coup for Israel but it's likely he was merely boasting on TV to the extent of Hamas influence and membership without realising - as he should have done being a spokesman for Hamas - how this would play out in the larger context.

This by the way is line with the analysis I presented above. I mean, that the affiliation of protestors to Hamas was irrelevant. The surprise here is that Hamas went ahead and released figures - with their experience of the media, and in particular, the Israeli media, especially on the ongoing climate of the 'war or terror', they should have known how this would have played into the hands of Israels PR machine.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer really addresses the question. You use the example of the Conservative government in the UK, saying that most citizens of Britain agree that they have a legitimate right to govern. But that doesn't make a Labour voter, say, a member of the Conservative Party! If I asked how many people at a protest were Conservatives, an answer saying "even Labour supports the legitimacy of Theresa May's government" would be beside the point.

Comment: Then you say that "It does not surprise me that Hamas has released no figures on the party political allegiance of those killed in the recent demonstrations." But they *have*. That's part of the basis of the question. They claim that about 50 of those killed belong to Hamas. Clearly *they* don't feel it's irrelevant.

Comment: Finally, the relevance of the question is clear. Israel has justified its actions by claiming that most of those killed were members of Hamas. To evaluate the truth of this argument, it's helpful to know whether those killed were Hamas supporters, not supporters, party members, military members, or what. Similarly, Hamas has claimed that it wasn't trying to sacrifice people's lives by making them approach the border, explicitly saying that most of those killed were its own members (and thus, why would it kill them?). Again, to evaluate this claim, it helps to know whether this is true.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: So you are saying that if the protestors were members of Hamas and *unarmed* it's fine to go ahead and shoot at will?

Comment: @Mozibar - If you think that's what the question's about, you might not have read it.

Comment: To be honest, you really do seem to be answering a different question. I was very clear in the notes: "I'm not asking whether belonging to Hamas is a bad thing, or whether it's justification for shooting someone." Obviously, I do have opinions about those questions, but they aren't what is being asked about here. Even in your edit, where you mention the statements of the Hamas spokesperson, you seem to be dealing more in how their statements are perceived, rather than their accuracy.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: I reported the view of a French journalist who was sceptical of the claims of both the Israeli & Hamas view and he substantiated by what he saw both at the protest and it's aftermath. Perceptions about what is reported or not reported in media, what is said or not said are important; spokespeople are generally talking to more than one audience. For example, I perceive you avoided answering the pointed question I asked in the comment above.

Comment: Your "pointed question" is precisely what I am trying to avoid with this question: getting bogged down in arguments about the ethics of Hamas and Israel's actions. Believe me, I have plenty of people to do that with. The relevance is that *Israel's government* argues that because (supposedly) most people protesting were members of Hamas, it was acceptable to shoot them if they approached the border. There are a variety of reasons one might disagree (including what you mentioned) but a big one might be if Israel was incorrect.

Comment: Conversely, even if Israel's government and the Hamas spokesperson are correct, one isn't obligated to accept Israel's position. One might believe that 100% of the protestors were armed Hamas soldiers, and still disagree with shooting them. Or, conversely, that none of them were affiliated with Hamas at all, and still think it was right (no, these are my opinions; they're arguments I've actually heard). But frankly, which people belonged to Hamas is important both to Hamas *and* Israel, and thus it's important to know the truth.

Comment: Remember, too: the question "Was Israel justified in shooting protesters who came near the border?" is of great moral importance, but definitely POB. So, one should rather ask about facts: Were protester with Hamas? Were they unarmed? Did Israel shoot people who didn't touch the wall? And so forth.

Comment: This answer is better after the edit but still needs some reorganisation and 'cleaning'.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: Well, I disagree. To go along checking whether protestors belong to Hamas is merely to fall in line with the Israeli narrative in branding every legitimate protest as 'terrorism' - something that if you read my answer you'll see they have admitted to as a submission to a high court. Political protest is a right that citizens have in a democracy, a description of itself that Israel is happy to go along with until there is some chance of upsetting the status quo.

Comment: @Evargalo: What did you have in mind, any tips?

Comment: @Mozibur - Well, it is a shame that Hamas is interested in telling us whether protesters belong to them, then! ;) If you weren't so insistent in answering a different question (which might explain some of the downvites) you might even notice that the top answer somewhat vindicates what you're saying. And even if you may believe that it's totally irrelevant whether Hamas was involved (which most people on *either* side, Hamas and IDF alike, don't) you might consider the value of this in convincing *other* people.

Comment: While I really do want to avoid making this into a discussion of Hamas and Israel's actions, I will say that my personal opinions are such that I don't think it's *totally* irrelevant to the broad characterization of the protests whether the protesters were mainly Hamas soldiers, Hamas supporters, non-Hamas supporters, Israeli agitators....

Comment: @Obie 2.0: I read the top answer and it doesn't vindicate what I'm saying. He merely mentions one report that I touched upon. One statement by a Hamas spokesman doesn't substantiate anything; as you yourself put in your question 'perhaps Hamas wants to make its support base larger than it is.'!

Comment: @Mozibur - Did you read the *top* answer? Its gist is "there's no reason to believe Hamas or IDF statements about the protesters' affiliation." Perhaps you're thinking of the *second*-most upvoted answer.

Comment: "To go along checking whether protestors belong to Hamas is merely to fall in line with the Israeli narrative in branding every legitimate protest as 'terrorism'" I disagree. Checking the truth of a statement is the basis of any rational discussion. Avoiding this to "not fall to opponent propaganda" is the optimal breeding ground for fake news and one-sided propaganda, and this site is an attempt to prevent exactly that.